# Should i really care about the thread safe issue in servlet Action class

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, thread-safety

A servlet class handles the incoming request object, fetch data & store into StringBuilder/StringBuffer and passes the data to another class to write into a file.

```
ActionClass
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
   throws ServletException,IOException {
        String fileName = request.getparameter("fileName");
        String body = request.getParameter("innerHTML");
        String head = request.getParameter("headContents");

        StringBuilder sbr = new StringBuilder();
        sbr.append(body);  sbr.append(head);
                        OR
        StringBuffer sbf = new StringBuffer();
         sbf.append(body);  sbf.append(head);

   FileWrite fw = new FileWrite(fileName, sbf/sbr); /* write the data into file*/
          }
```

***FileWrite***

```
    class FileWrite{
       public FileWrite(String fileName, StringBuilder sbf){
        boolean isExist = checkFileName(fileName);  /* return true or false */
         if(isExist){
           String name =  reName(fileName);  /* rename & return new name */
                 /* write the file in new file */
          }else{  /* write in same file name */  }
      }

   public String reName(String oldName){
             /* rename oldName as newName & checks via isExist(newName) */
            } 

   public boolean isExist(String filename) {
         // checks the file in directory, if found already
       return true;
           else return false;
         }
    }
```

as you can see in above example, action class passes the data to `FileWrite class` which writes the data to a new file. there are hundreds of client might sent the request at same time to store the data in new file.
so my question is, ***in servlet class what should i use to store the data.*** is it `String or stringBuffer or StringBuilder`?? is it issue of thread safe?

Comment: I would recommend that you show what method you are putting the code in, so that we don't have to make assumptions (per Neil's comment about doGet or doPost)

Comment: @Nathan: i have modified & written the other class & method too. whether i am not sure the `FileWrite class or it's method` need to be thread safe or not but i hope you may get my point now. thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should care about thread safety issues, but the issue with thread safety isn't in your choice of String or stringBuffer or StringBuilder.

Where you need to watch out (potentially) for thread safety is if you get two requests for the same filename to your FileWriter class.

Also, I would note that it is quite dangerous from a security standpoint to simply take raw file locations directly from a get parameter - as users can overwrite other user files, or (potentially, depending on permissions) even OS files.

Comment: very brilliant answer. yes the file name might be overwritten but i have another application which checks the existing file name, if the file name is the same then it renames the file and inform to client.

Comment: Nathan, as you said and I strogly feel that there must be thread safety issue in  `FileWriter class` therefore what would be right way to make sure to thread safe the method. `static synchronized method() or synchronized method`

Answer (score 2):

As long as it is happening inside the doGet or doPost of your servlet then you are only dealing with one thread. Thus, no need for thread safety which means you should use StringBuilder which is faster than StringBuffer.

Comment: I think you meant "no need for Thread safety" not "no need for Type safety"

Comment: great, the same thing i was thinking but i wasn't so confident and couldn't find the answer on google too. many thank.

Answer (score 1):

For every new request, a new servlet thread is spawned having its own properly wrapped unique context. So the data inside doPost doGet gets saved in that context and is thus safe from other requests.

As far as String vs StringBuffer vs StringBuilder is considered, since the context itself is thread safe, there are no synchronization issues and so you can go for springbuilder.

On a side note: if there are no changes going to happen, why not go for simple string ??

By the way.. look out for two requests coming for the same file!!

Comment: yes, i was thinking to use String only but the fear of thread safe compells me to think about StringBuffer Vs StringBuilder. that is why i just asked this question. many thanks Nikunj

Answer (score 0):

From Java doc.

Instances of StringBuilder are not safe for use by multiple threads. If such synchronization is required then it is recommended that StringBuffer be used.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

First of all Strings are internalized.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()

Which means if you have identical strings, it is not an issue.

*If your header and footer are static, it could be in a static variable.*

Answer (score 0):

if you declare variable inside a method  it will be put in a place call thread-stack  that is accessible to only the current thread .so you dont have to worry about thread safety as long as it a local variable 
in your case you should use StringBuider because it's faster no need to worry about thread safety here

Answer (score -1):

your coder is Thread safe , this has not problem in Multi threaded environment .Because your ServleClass does not have Class level or Instance level variables, your FileWrite is Instance in the method of post . erver request will have a new FileWrite..